# Input a command result in a command line program

Tags: shell, exploit

I got a command line program ./a.out which asks me to input something as shown below:

```
$ ./a.out
Adress is 0x8048508
Please input a choice:
```

And I want to input

```
python -c 'print "A"*56 + "BBBB" + "\x08\x85\x04\x08"'
```

Despite from using pip(cannot use here cuz the address is dynamic).
How can I do it?

Many thanks for any thoughts or ideas.

Answer (score 0):

If the program just reads from standard input then `python -c 'print "A"*56 + "BBBB" + "\x08\x85\x04\x08"' | ./a.out` should work.

If it is reading from the terminal then that won't and you would have to fake an interactive session (with something like [expect](http://wiki.tcl.tk/11583) to inject the input you want.

Comment: Interesting! I got the impression that the output from `a.out` was supposed to be re-jigged and fed into the python!

Comment: @MarkSetchell Interesting indeed. Re-reading it I don't quite see your interpretation (though I almost do) but I do see an alternative which is that the literal string of the python command is supposed to be the input instead. But that's the same basic concept as my current answer.